# How can I use a template with a changing value for a grunt-contrib-copy cwd property

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have a grunt build that should do the following:

- Copy items from a location
- Load a package.json file from those copied files and extract a version number
- Copy items from a folder dependent on that version number

I have a task that reads the version number:

```
grunt.task.registerTask(
    "readVersionNumber",
    "Reads a version number",
    function(){
        var versionNumber = grunt.file.readJSON("pathToJson");
        grunt.config.set("versionNumber",versionNumber);
    }
);
```

(typed out rather than copy/paste so possibly some minor typos)

and I have a copy task with a cwd:

`"cwd": "//networkPath/<%= versionNumber %>/docs"`

But this is not working...

I have a very similar setup for replacing text in html / js files and looking at the `grunt-text-replace.js` file it uses `grunt.template.process` to replace the template in the string with the actual value. I suspect that for the copy task this is done before the copy task starts (before I have loaded and set the version number).

I can't find much info on how the `cwd` property is evaluated except that it seems to happen in the guts of grunt itself. It seems odd that core grunt functionality would not properly process templates but from what I can see it's not happening.

BTW - all this works fine if I use a template pointing to a value in my package.json file:

`"cwd": "//networkPath/<%= pkg.path.to.version %>/docs"`

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could consider:

1. Dynamically obtaining the version from`package.json` whilst copying the items from your location, using the [options.process](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#process) function.
2. Storing it as a property in an initially empty object.
3. Then referencing it later in another `copy` task target.

The following gist seems to work:

#### Gruntfile.js

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        // A 'version' property key and value (obtained via a copied package.json)
        // will be dynamically added to this empty object and referenced later.
        obtainedFromPackage: {},

        copy: {
            options: {
                // Avoid binaries getting corrupted. For more info see:
                // https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/213
                noProcess: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,pdf}']
            },
            initial: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/',
                    src: '**/*',
                    dest: './copiedItems/'
                }],
                options: {
                    // Use/abuse the 'options.process' function to obtain the 'version'
                    // value from the copied 'package.json'. This value is added to a
                    // 'version' property in the empty 'obtainedFromPackage' object.
                    process: function(content, srcpath) {
                        if (srcpath.indexOf('package.json') !== -1) {
                            var pkgVersion = grunt.file.readJSON(srcpath).version;
                            grunt.config('obtainedFromPackage.version', pkgVersion);
                        }
                        return content //Ensure original file content is not deleted.
                    }
                }
            },
            copyDocs : {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    // Change directory to version obtained in previous copy task.
                    cwd: './networkPath/<%= obtainedFromPackage.version %>/',
                    src: 'docs/**',
                    dest: './copiedItems/'
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

    grunt.registerTask('copyFiles', [
        'copy:initial',
        'copy:copyDocs'
    ]);

};
```

**Note:** This will obviously need adapting to suit your requirements.
Particularly the path references!

#### Directory setup

The example gist in the `Gruntfile.js` assumes a fictitious project directory set up as follows:

```
project
├── Gruntfile.js (the one shown above)
├── networkPath
│  ├── 0.0.0
│  │  └── docs
│  │      ├── baz
│  │      │   └── baz.html
│  │      └── index.html
│  └── 1.1.1
│     └── docs
│         ├── foo
│         │   └── foo.html
│         └── index.html
├─── node_modules
│     └── ...
├─── package.json
└─── src
    ├─── a
    │   └─── b.js
    └─── package.json
```

...Whereby the `version` property of `package.json`, (the one residing in the `src` folder), is set to:

```json
"version": "1.1.1",
```

...and the folder named *networkPath* is what I'm assuming to be where your docs are stored.

#### Running the task

Execute the following command via the CLI:

`$ grunt copyFiles`

#### Resultant output

Running the task creates a new folder in the root `project` directory as follows:

```
project
├── copiedItems
│  ├── a
│  │  └── b.js
│  ├── docs
│  │  ├── foo
│  │  │   └── foo.html
│  │  └── index.html
│  └─── package.json
├─ ...
└─ ...
```

**Points to note:**

1. All the items from the `src` folder (the one shown in the ***Directory setup*** section above) are copied to the newly created folder named *copiedItems*.
2. The `docs` folder and its contents from the folder named *1.1.1* (the one shown in the ***Directory setup*** section above) are copied to the newly created folder named *copiedItems*. This particular folder is being copied because its parent directory name matches the version property of package.json being copied.

I hope this helps!

---

#### Update:

**When adding some binary images to the `src` folder, I've since discovered that the resultant copied images were getting corrupted. See this [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/213) logged in the `grunt-contrib-copy` repo for further info.**

**The `Gruntfile.js` above now utilizes the [options.noprocess](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#noprocess) as a global in the `copy` task as a safeguard from this.**

**Image files are now copied successfully :)**

---

Comment: I copied your code and tried it out locally but got the same result that I did with my code. Your code isn't that much different really, just getting the value from the package.json differently. That was never a problem.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that I am using an old version of the copy library. I see that there are several new versions. I don't currently have e access to the latest so I'll have to request it.

Comment: f.y.i. the version I used was  `grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0` - Now curious to know what you mean by _"got the same result that I did with my code"_... What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: The second copy task runs but nothing happens. It's annoying that you can't see what path it is trying to copy from but no files were copied so something is not working.
Many thanks for your post, I'll update this when I am able to get the latest version.

Comment: Good luck! You could try running the task with the `--verbose` flag via the CLI. For example: `$ grunt copyFiles --verbose`. It might help to reveal what's not working.

Comment: Yeah, I tried --verbose --debug --stack, no useful info given!